# My Api is not work from ASP.NET Core with Angular Example Template

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I make api from "ASP.NET Core Web Api" Template. And its work, Active PostMan.
So I Copy that to "ASP.NET Core with Angular" Template.

But Its not work. Just 404 NOT FOUND ERROR.
What am I wrong?

```
--Controller
...(Skip)...

[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class RestaurantController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IRestaurantService _service;

    public RestaurantController(IRestaurantService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    // Restaurant/Restaurants
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Restaurants")]
    public IActionResult GetRestaurantList()
    {
        return CheckErrors(_service.GetRestaurantList());
    }

...(Skip)...
```

```
--Angular.ts
...(Skip)...

export class FetchDataComponent {
  public forecasts: WeatherForecast[] = [];

  constructor(http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
    http.get<WeatherForecast[]>(baseUrl + 'Restaurant/Restaurants').subscribe(result => {
      console.log("", result);
      this.forecasts = result;
    }, error => console.error(error));
  }
}

interface WeatherForecast {
  id: number;
  text: string;
}
```

```
--Angular.html
...(Skip)...

<table class='table table-striped' aria-labelledby="tableLabel" *ngIf="forecasts">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>text</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let forecast of forecasts">
      <td>{{ forecast.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ forecast.text }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I think its work, but console.log("", result) where Chrome F12 Console Browser show me Eorror

```
--Error 404

HttpErrorResponse
error: "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n<head>\n<meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n<title>Error</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<pre>Cannot GET /Restaurant/Restaurants</pre>\n</body>\n</html>\n"
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message: "Http failure response for https://localhost:44450/Restaurant/Restaurants: 404 Not Found"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 404
statusText: "Not Found"
url: "https://localhost:44450/Restaurant/Restaurants"
[[Prototype]]: HttpResponseBase
```

And This is my result Picture where APS.NET Core Web Api Template

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ol0IN.png)

Comment: Wrong port. From your screenshot https://localhost:**7285** while in Angular, you call API with https://localhost:**44450**. Make sure your `BASE_URL` has the correct value for the API url.

Comment: @YongShun
Yes, After I submit this question, I found when start my asp.net core with angular template, the port is change to proxy port. before change proxy port, a little time can see Noproxy port. And I test it and work! my api is work! Now My problem is change. Find that change proxy port function and delete it. thx